# Easy way to render JSON with HTTP status code in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Is there a shorthand way to do this without explicit `"text/json"` designation?

```
def remoteError = {     
  render( status: 500, contentType: "text/json"){
      error( exception: "a remote exception occurred")
  }
}
```

I tried using `as JSON`...no content is returned but the status code is correct...

```
render( status: 500, exception: params.exception) as JSON
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you use a converter parameter to [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) then you cannot specify any other parameter such as status like you normally would when using gsp views.  You can however set the response status prior to calling render:

```
response.status = 500
render([error: 'an error occurred'] as JSON)
```

Comment: This actually throws a cast exception because `params.exception` is a string. I tried `def errorMsg = [error: 'an error occurred']` `render errorMsg as JSON`, that works.

Comment: @RaffiM of course, I changed my answer to render a map instead of a string which won't work.

Comment: had to make another slight adjustment, `render ([error: 'sdf'] as JSON)`, thx for the tips

Answer (score 2):

```
render(status:500,text:(errors as JSON).toString(),contentType: 'application/json')
```